# Dynamically get the total up/down time from a log file

Tags: ruby, logging, scripting

Let's say I have the following log file that continuously logs a server's down/up time:

**status.log**

```
UP - "18:00:00"
..
..
DOWN - "19:00:03"
..
..
DOWN - "22:00:47"
..
..
UP - "23:59:48"
UP - "23:59:49"
UP - "23:59:50"
DOWN - "23:59:51"
DOWN - "23:59:52"
UP - "23:59:53"
UP - "23:59:54"
UP - "23:59:56"
UP - "23:59:57"
UP - "23:59:59"
```

each day is logged in a separate folder under the same filename.

***not my actual code, but this is much simpler and transparent approach:***

```
#!/bin/ruby
downtime_log = File.readlines("path/to/log/file").select { |line| line =~ /DOWN/ }
puts "#{downtime_log.count} Downtimes for today"
```

logic-wise, how can I get the total downtime per file/day in minutes and seconds but not as a total count.

Comment: I think you misunderstood that. I read that as _homework help questions_ are off-topic unless they _include a summary of the work you've done so far_ and _a description of the difficulty you are having solving it_. What makes sense because we do not want to solve your homework, but we love to help you when you are facing a problem.

Comment: Including what you tried is just good sense; it's the *share your research* part of our question asking guidelines.  That way people can focus their help on your specific situation far better. Note that commenting on votes (up or down) is never required, nor can moderators do anything about individual votes.

Comment: thanks for the illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your file contains exactly one line per second. Then the number of seconds your service was down can be evaluated like you already did in your approach:

```
number_of_seconds_downtime = File.readlines('path/to/log/file')
                                 .select { |line| line =~ /DOWN/ }
                                 .count
```

Or simplified:

```
number_of_seconds_downtime = File.readlines('path/to/log/file')
                                 .count { |line| line =~ /DOWN/ }
```

To translate this into minutes and seconds just [`divmod`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod)

```
minutes, seconds = number_of_seconds_downtime.divmod(60)
```

and output the result like this:

```
puts "#{minutes}:#{seconds} downtime"
```

Comment: counting lines in seconds makes sense, that way i can change it to minutes, and do a hour minute output forexample. thanks a lot